# AccountNotFoundError: The account of type [BidReceipt] was not found at the provided address

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, solana-cli, metaplex-js, auction-house

I am encountering errors when using the Metaplex SDK. When I attempt to list an NFT on the auction house and place a bid on an NFT, I receive these error messages. The transactions appear to go through successfully, and I can see the listings and bids on Solscan, but when I check the terminal, it displays these errors. Interestingly, when I run the script again, it works without issues and provides a response with signatures, but when I run script first time, its show those error.

Could you please assist me in understanding whether these issues are related to the Metaplex SDK?

Error:
Listing
----- FailedToConfirmTransactionError: The transaction could not be confirmed. Please check the underlying error below for more details.

Source: RPC

Caused By: [object Object]

Bidding
----- AccountNotFoundError: The account of type [BidReceipt] was not found at the provided address [9DZF9Bz2Y7qeNNhgX1HpoedSZa5S72moAdR3nKvfo8we].

Source: SDK

Answer (score 1):

If everything looks OK in Solscan it means it worked fine.

`AccountNotFoundError` error probably happens because you're trying to fetch the `account` too early after it was created (there is a small delay between a tx being sent and it being finalized on the chain).

To fix this ideally you should wait a bit after sending a tx before you fetch the newly created `account`, or you could also configure your web3 connection to use `processed` or `confirmed` as commitment levels. [More info.](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/types/Commitment.html)

Eg: `await metaplex.connection.getAccountInfo(myAccount, "processed");`

Comment: Thanks for reply
But I can't create any account while listing or bidding, find the auction house details and list like this

const list = await metaplex.auctionHouse().list({
      auctionHouse: auctionHouse,
      mintAccount: nft_address,
      price: amount,
    });

then where I can use Proceed or confirmed